# Allocation of value types

Tags: c#, .net, clr, value-type

When you assign an instance of a value type to another instance, the object is copied bit-by-bit to the target location:

```
private struct Word
{
    public Word(char c) { ... }
}

public void Method(Word a)
{
    Word b = a; //a is copied and stored in b
}
```

But given the following code:

```
private Word _word;

public void Method() {
    _word = new Word('x');
}
```

I suspect that the right-hand side (RHS) expression is evaluated first - which instantiates a value type on the stack - and *then* the value is copied and stored on the location of the `_word` field, which is on the heap.

The alternative would be to take the left-hand side into consideration, and instantiate the value type directly on `_word`, avoiding having to copy the object.

Is my suspicion correct? If it is, I suppose it's safe to assume that the first block of code would perform better than the second.

```
//1 instantiation + 10k copies
Word[] words = new Word[10000];
Word word = new Word('x');

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    words[i] = word;


//10k instantiations + 10k copies
Word[] words = new Word[10000];

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    words[i] = new Word('x');
```

Note: I'm not trying to micro-optimize anything.

**Edit**: The core of my question is, as Lee puts it: Are structs allocated in place directly, or do they need to be allocated then copied?

Comment: I think you meant that last line to be words[i] = new Word(); . The answer might be interesting but I think if it can be optimized it will be.

Comment: If you're just calling the default constructor then the loops could be removed entirely couldn't they? Structs are already zero-initialised.

Comment: @Lee Yes, but that's not the point. This is just an example to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: Maybe this is unspecified because you can't tell the difference under single-threaded execution. Of course if the ctor were to execute side-effects your two code snippets would not be equivalent.

Comment: @dcastro. Seems that I was mistaken after all. But the man himself answered you :)

Comment: What is the use case?   Do you really need to make multiple copies of the same struct?

Comment: @Blam There is no use case, I'm asking this out of curiosity.

Comment: But you use terms of one preferred over the other.  To me that implies more than curiosity.

Comment: @Blam those are just examples to pit one hypothesis against the other ^^ I made those up, they're not taken from a project.

Comment: Interesting curiosity. When you bring in a real or contrived use case and use the term preferred you imply more than a curiosity with no use case. Suggest you make that more clear in the question.

Comment: @Blam I believe the last paragraph marked as *edit* makes it clear that the question is about what happens during the allocation/assignment, and not about the examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> When you assign an instance of a value type to another instance, the object is copied bit-by-bit to the target location

When you assign an instance of a value type to a variable of the same type, the value is copied to the target location, yes. But that is true of reference types as well: the *reference* is copied bit by bit to the target location. The *referent* of course stays right where it is.

> I suspect that the right-hand side (RHS) expression is evaluated first

The specification states that the left hand side is evaluted to produce a variable, then the right hand side is evaluated to produce a value, and then the assignment happens.

In the examples you give the evaluation of the left hand side does not produce an observable side effect and therefore its evaluation can be re-ordered by the optimizers in the C# compiler, the jitter or the CPU if any of them so choose. But if you had something like

```
x[i++] = v();
```

then the side effect on the left hand side has to happen before the call on the right hand side.

> The core of my question is: Are structs allocated in place directly, or do they need to be allocated then copied?

The specification states that structures are allocated in a temporary location -- which would typically be the stack or a register in practice -- and then copied to their final destination.  However, there are some situations in which the optimizer can determine that it is impossible for the user to notice if the mutation happens "in place" at the final destination. This is a *copy elision* optimization, and the C# compiler will perform this optimization if it feels it can get away with it.

For more details see my article on the subject:

http://ericlippert.com/2010/10/11/debunking-another-myth-about-value-types/

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation - specially the blog post which explains *why* structs are allocated in a temporary location (in most cases). I suppose then, from the two code samples I provided, the first would be better because it would avoid allocating the struct in a temporary location over and over again (assuming there's no *copy elision*), is that correct?

Comment: Oh, and when I said "the RHS expression is evaluated first", what I meant to say was: "the RHS and the LHS are evaluated independently". As in, the LHS doesn't affect the allocation of the struct, which I now know is not necessarily true.

Comment: @dcastro: The C# compiler only elides copies when the target is a local variable; in your examples the target is an array element. The real savings between your first and second examples is likely not in the copying but rather in avoiding calling the constructor 9999 times.

Answer (score 0):

Are either preferred?

What is the business case for multiple identical structs?
If you need multiple identical objects is a struct the best choice?

A struct (re)initialized in that manner is probably not a good solution for the example use case
In the new array the WordStruct is allocated and initialized using the default ctor (no ctor)
You don't have the option to initialize a struct array with another ctor
If you do need identical structs then this would be preferred

```
WordStruct[] WordStructS = new WordStruct[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < WordStructS.Length; i++) { WordStructS[i].C = 'x'; }
```

If multiple identical objects what you really need to do then consider a class
A class new array is allocated but not yet initialized
You don't waste resources initializing with the default constructor

```
WordClass[] WordClassS = new WordClass[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < WordClassS.Length; i++) { WordClassS[i] = new WordClass('x'); }
```

If you want to generalize deep copy of an object (struct or class) then consider IConable
In the case of a struct I suspect it is more efficient than a bit wise copy (but I am not positive)
In the case of class it will make a clone (deep copy) not a reference

```
public struct WordStruct : ICloneable 
{
    public char C;
    public WordStruct(char C) 
    {
        this.C = C;
    }
    public object Clone()
    {
        WordStruct newWordStruct = (WordStruct)this.MemberwiseClone();
        return newWordStruct;
    }
}
```

I know in a comment you said curiosity but that is not clear in the question
In the question you state first block of code is preferred over the second

I get it is an interesting question of curiosity
But if it is just curiosity then the question should have stopped at
Is my suspicion correct?